# Accessing a database through a function in PHP 7.2 not working

Tags: php, jquery, function, php-7.2

I'm trying to use a simple query though a function, it is not working and I have no clue why.

This code woks perfectly outside a function:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
$NEWUSER = "jack";

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name FROM Users WHERE user_name = '$NEWUSER'");
$result = implode("",$query->fetch_assoc());
echo $result;
```

However when I place it in a function it ceases to work!?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
$NEWUSER = "jack";

someFunction();

function someFunction() {
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name FROM Users WHERE user_name = '$NEWUSER'");
    $result = implode("",$query->fetch_assoc());
    echo $result;
}
```

I'm woking on upgrading my PHP 5.5 site to 7.2 and I don't understand what am I doing wrong because this worked just fine previously, thanks.

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Thats a better reference than my answer :) I'm voting dupe as well.

Comment: Your answer is good tho :D It solves OP's issue and allows them to move on. The duplicate can just give some more infos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with a variable inside the function, which does not exist. You must pass the `$mysqli` object variable (and `$NEWUSER`) in like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
$NEWUSER = "jack";

someFunction($NEWUSER,$mysqli);
//              ^--------^---- note passing it in along with the NEWUSER var

function someFunction($NEWUSER,$mysqli) {
//                       ^--------^---- define them for pass-in
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name FROM Users WHERE user_name = '$NEWUSER'");
    $result = implode("",$query->fetch_assoc());
    echo $result;
}
```

---

As a side note, this is very odd:

```
$result = implode("",$query->fetch_assoc());
echo $result;
```

You can get away with just this in php7:

```
echo $query->fetch_assoc()['user_name'];
```

Or:

```
echo $query->fetch_object()->user_name;
```

Comment: ah, I did't realize that I had to pass all variables though. My assumption was any variable outside the function would wok in the function like in JS.  THANKS!

Comment: Correct. This gets a bit different in a class, where you can keep the db object in a class variable and access it directly in methods inside that class. But an example of that was a bit much to add :) Whatever you do, DONT succumb to just using `global` everywhere ;)